# django :keyword can't be an expression

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to filter objects using partial matching.

I am trying -

```
response = {}
pid = post['id'].split('_')[0]
response['product'] = list(product_details.objects.filter(p_id.split('_')[0] = pid).values())
```

But I am getting error -

```
keyword can't be an expression
```

Is there any shorter way to perform the task. I want the objects whose first part of `id` matches with the first part of `post['id']`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because that will give error - `too many values to unpack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `startswith` lookup:

```
list(product_details.objects.filter(p_id__startswith=pid + '_').values())
```